# RESTful web services 500 or 406 Error when "£" is in a value

Tags: 7

I'm using RESTful web services and Node.js to export a Mongo database into Drupal. This is working fine, however I get the occasional 500 or 406 error. I've narrowed it down to a "£" sign. In node I'm doing an http request using the below. All this works fine apart from the £ sign. Do I have to do a character replace for each string or something?

```
...
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    ...
```

This is the JSON:

```
{ 
    "type": 'primary_whatson',
    "field_parent_article": { 
        "uri": 'http://tp/cms/node/702', 
        "id": '702', 
        "resource": 'node' },
        "field_whatson_theme": { 
            "uri": 'http://tp/cms/taxonomy/term/385',
        "id": '385',
        "resource": 'taxonomy_term' 
    },
    "title": 'Test',
    "field_body": { 
        "value": '<p>test.</p>',
        "summary": '',
        "format": 'filtered_html' 
    },
    "field_ticket_price_v": "Tickets free-£9.00"
}
```

Comment: Is it Drupal to throw 500 or 406, or the other side? Also, "406 Not Acceptable" seems pretty self-explanatory. Are you sure both sides can treat the £ the same way? And that both are really utf-8? And that both in fact *can* use utf-8? Maybe one of your sides, or some proxy, can't, and £ prevents ASCII fallback? Just guessing now.

Comment: It is Drupal, via the RESTful module. The error does not give me anything helpful. A 406 would be self explanatory, but referring back to my question where a "£" exists in the JSON file, I get either a 406 or a 500. It is UTF-8 on both sides yes. Yeah I'm guessing too. I'm just running it locally so no proxy issue. I will keep digging. Thanks for taking a look dude